# ¿Como ejecutar una funcion, luego de haber obtener un valor del servidor, jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, funciones

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente función donde me devuelve el valor `idPedido`

```
function obtenerPedido() {
     axios.get(`https://URL/Pedido?CodigoCliente=${codclienteAfiliadoPedido}&Cod_Trib=${cod_trib}&TipoSocio=${idtiposocio}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    myApp.showIndicator();
                    console.log(response);
                    localStorage.setItem("IDPedido", response.data.IDPedido);
                    idPedido = localStorage.getItem("IDPedido");//Aca guardo el id del pedido.
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                });
}
```

El detalle surge que antes de que en la funcion anterior obtenga el idPedido se ejecuta esta otra función y el problema es de que para que esta función se ejecute bien necesita del parametro idPedido:

```
function listarPedido() {
    idPedido = localStorage.getItem("IDPedido");
        axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://URL/AppListaPedido?IDPedido=${idPedido}&TipoEnvio=${TipoEnvio}&Cod_Agencia=${cod_agencia}&Cod_depto=${cod_depto}&ProductoGratis=${ProductoGratis}&EquipoSocioNuevo=${EquipoSocioNuevo}&Cod_cliente=${cod_cliente}`,
        headers: {
            Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
        }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);                
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                myApp.hideIndicator();
            });
}
```

Para dicha situación no quiero tener la funcion `listarPedido()` dentro de la funcion `obtenerPedido()`

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero despues del ajax de la primera función como llamas a la otra función listarPedido? es decir si una funcion depende de otra en la primera tienes que llamarla cuando sea success el ajax

Comment: intente agregar listarPedido(); cuando sea success, pero no envia el parametro idPedido. Por ejemplo cuando entro a la vista donde se ejecuta listarPedido la primera vez no reconoce idPedido, pero al regresar a la vista anterior y luego regresar a donde ejecuto listarPedido ahi ya funciona.

Comment: intentastes colorcarlo asi? : `}).then(function (response) {
                                                   listarPedido(response.data.IDPedido);` y luego recibirla asi: `function listarPedido(idPedido) {`